# Why Label Width does not work inside ChangePassword control ? asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, label, change-password

I have a `ChangePassword` control and I converted it to a template. I removed all of the table code and tried to format everything myself. When I set the `Width` property of the `Label` control, I found it does not work. Can anyone see what I might be doing wrong?

Code Sample (stripped down):

```
    <asp:ChangePassword ID="ChangePassword1" runat="server">
    <ChangePasswordTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="CurrentPasswordLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="CurrentPassword" Width="250">Password:</asp:Label>

    <asp:Button ID="CancelPushButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel" />                                                   
    </ChangePasswordTemplate>
</asp:ChangePassword>
```

Comment: It probably renders, but not have 250px to spread. Do you have the html source code of render to see if exist ?

Comment: This example suggests using CSS: http://forums.asp.net/t/1160671.aspx

Comment: Thanks Aristos but it's not about that.

Comment: Thanks lhan16 .. the link you shared with me did help to me .. that guy asked technically the same question and the solution that posted works for me as well. You may promote this as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [asp:label width - is this a bug?](http://forums.asp.net/t/1160671.aspx)

It suggests using `CSS` to solve the same problem you're having.

Comment: As per comments in the link adding float:left; solved this for me too

Answer (score 1):

Just make `label` float left.

```
<label id="pwd">Password:</label>
```

The Css:

```
#pwd {
     float:left;    // This will make the width works.
     width:100px;
}
```